# Spotify SDK Demo Swift works but cannot be translated to Storyboard-based project

Tags: ios, swift, sdk, spotify

Plan: Spotify Premium Country: Belgium Device: iPhone 11 Pro Max Operating System: iOS 13.5 + macOS Catalina

I installed and the iOS SDK properly in Xcode (https://github.com/spotify/ios-sdk) and set up the server token swap and refresh properly => [demo swift login](https://github.com/spotify/ios-sdk/tree/master/DemoProjects/SPTLoginSampleAppSwift/SPTLoginSampleAppSwift) works nicely.

Now I'm trying to integrate that into my iOS application and it doesn't work at all. I tested everything that was possible and I broke it down to the least changes to the demo to better understand what could cause it to fail. See hereunder:

I set up a basic Xcode iOS app
I don't use create the views using programmation as in the demo, I use the Storyboard (only difference with the demo code)
I set everything exactly the same, it builds and it runs on the iPhone device nicely without any error or any alert message
when I click "Connect", it asks permission to use "Spotify" as expected, I answer yes, it switches to Spotify and starts playing the song
it switches back to my app and still shows the "Connect" button
When debugging, I set up breakpoints at every sessionManager, application methods and appRemote event functions, none of them is apparently caught. When I do the same in the demo project, it stops at breakpoints

My conclusions:

the delegates do not work and seem not to be assigned correctly because no event is caught
What is strange? It's line per line EXACTLY the same code as the demo project, only I use Scenes so I have a SceneDelegate.swift file in my project.

I tried to transfer some of the code like the delegate assignment to the SceneDelegate file to the corresponding events but it doesn't work well and the openURL method is not the same as in the application open url method so I don't know how to translate the openURL call at scene level:

application-level openURL

```
func application(_ app: UIApplication, open url: URL, options: [UIApplication.OpenURLOptionsKey : Any] = [:]) -> Bool {
    
    rootViewController.sessionManager.application(app, open: url, options: options)
    return true
}
```

scene-level openURL

```
func scene(_ scene: UIScene, openURLContexts URLContexts: Set<UIOpenURLContext>) {
    
    
}
```

I'm lost, I spent 3 days trying everything and nothing works. BTW, I use regularly the Web API without any problem so I understand pretty well the Spotify auth process.

Can anybody help me? Because the iOS examples, to be honest, they are pretty thin to find solutions.

Or at least give me tips please, I'm stuck.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62478992) github answer might help you. It tells you what needs to go into the scene level openURL:

```
func scene(_ scene: UIScene, openURLContexts URLContexts: Set<UIOpenURLContext>) {

    print("Opened url")
    guard let url = URLContexts.first?.url else {
        return
    }
    lobbyAdminVC.sessionManager.application(UIApplication.shared, open: url, options: [:])
}
```